# Jquery - remove first item then select every second item in array with array.prototype

Tags: jquery, arrays

How would one remove 'RemoveThis' and then select every 0 (every 2nd item in array after removing the first item)?

```
var newItems = "RemoveThis,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0",
    everyThirdItem = newItems.split(",")
                       .filter(function(_, idx) { return ((idx + 1) % 2) === 0 });

console.log(everyThirdItem)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get remaining element except the first.

```js
var newItems = "RemoveThis,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0",
  everyThirdItem = newItems.split(",")
  .slice(1)
  .filter(function(_, idx) {
    return ((idx + 1) % 2) === 0
  });

console.log(everyThirdItem)
```

---

Or update the filter condition to avoid first element.

```js
var newItems = "RemoveThis,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0",
  everyThirdItem = newItems.split(",")
  .filter(function(_, idx) {
    return idx != 0 && idx % 2 === 0
  });

console.log(everyThirdItem)
```